# Sampling a function at a single point using unit impulse

Tags: signal-processing

I was watching [this video on signal processing:](https://youtu.be/sSU57kZhMSc?t=5m21s)

[image]

, and the author was trying to derive a function such that

$$
y(t) = \begin{cases}
x(\tau) & \mbox{if } t = \tau, \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The answer is $\int_{-\infty}^{\tau+} x(\tau) \delta(t-\tau) dt$, where $\delta$ is the unit impulse. I understand how this works, but I am wondering, why all the trouble for such a simple thing? Why not just use the first definition above?

Comment: Cf Dirac delta function (functional)

Comment: "Why not just use the first definition above" How? BTW, It is already "used"!

Comment: As long as $x(t)$ is defined, $y(t)$ is easily defined (in two cases, as shown), hence the integration approach doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: OK. I will give you an answer. But I think the condition should be $t=\tau$ (not $x=\tau$). Right?

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a typo. Will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The dirac delta $\delta$ is not a function; it is a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function). As an example application, the convolution property that you hint at is used to create [fundamental solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution) of linear operators. You may encounter such differential equations in signal processing.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the second form, with the integral, seems unnecessarily complex, it is more compact in the sense that it gets rid of the `if`/`else` condition and becomes a linear operation. This can be more readily plugged into other equations and derivations.

For example, this can be used when computing the Fourier transform of the dirac-delta function itself.

In my experience, it keeps popping up as a simplifying step in other derivations, where you notice the term $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau) \delta(t-\tau) dt$, as a part of something bigger, and simply replace with $x(\tau)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, in signal processing we use filters to obtain the desired output. So for any desired output there exists a filter, and an LTI filter is identified by its impulse response.

LTI filtering is defined as a convolution integral. So we look for a function $h(t)$ that satisfies $$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(\tau) h(t-\tau) d\tau$$
and $h(t)$ is simply the impulse response of the filter.
If we put $h(t)=\delta(t)$, it means the output to the Dirac delta impulse input is the *same* Dirac delta impulse. Hence $h(t)=\delta(t)$ is the identity system.
If you are familiar with Fourier (or $z$) transform, you can see that $$y(t)=x(t)\star\delta(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(\tau) \delta(t-\tau) d\tau$$
is written in the Fourier (or $z$) domain as 
$$Y(\omega)=X(\omega)$$